# launch class activity from main activity error

Tags: java, android

For some reason, although i created the class Speak2 , my program does not find it:

```
public class recon extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
ListView lv;
static final int check = 2000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.voice);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bVoice);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(recon.this , Speak2.class); 
    startActivity(i);
    }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}




}
```

I have also added to the manifest:

```
<Activity android:name="Speak2"/>
```

But i get error:

2-31 11:49:43.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4104): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.voice.recon/voice.Speak2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

is their some path issues in my code or? Please advise?

```
manifest current code:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.voice.recon"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="voice.recon" >

        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Speak2"/>


</application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the entry for the Speak2 activity in your manifest to:

`<activity android:name="voice.Speak2"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Have added this new Activity to you manifest file ?

[Useful guide for Manifest file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="package.namee"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityClassPath"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

In android, for you to start an activity, you have to add it to the AndroidManifest.xml file using  tag. Unless this is done, runtime will give you an error, when attempting to initiate the activity.

In the above case, the error is NOT that, the compiler is unable to find your class. Rather, the error is because you are missing the entry in manifest

Here are some reference URLs

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Declare

```
 <activity  android:name=".recon"></activity>
```

in your manifest between the

```
<application/>
```

Tags